# AngularJS two objects in the same ng-repet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can i have two objects in the same time in ng-repeat ?

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets |session in sessions |filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
```

Comment: no. use a nested repeater instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the items at the same index you can use the $index property:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets|filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
  <td>{{target}}  {{sessions[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
```